# Can secp256k1 have different parameters and still be called secp256k1?

Tags: secp256k1

The secp256k1 standard (as defined in https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf, section 2.4.1) has a set of recommended parameters.

- Is there a particular reason why these parameters are just 'recommended', and not 'required'?
- Are we still talking about 'secp256k1' if different parameters are used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SEC2 document recommends the use of a number of curves. One of these curves is called `secp256k1`.

The recommendation doesn't refer to the parameters. What is recommended is the use of the `secp256k1` curve and the parameters are integral to how the curve is defined. If you use any other parameters, you can't call it `secp256k1`.